# "Roll your balls to"

Tags: offensive-language

Does anyone say like this in this understanding? From
[Urban Dictionary](http://roll-your-balls-to.urbanup.com/16895028):

> Usually used as 'to roll one's balls to sb';
> Usually used towards girls by dudes;
> Meaning to flirt with a girl so as to eventually get conducted to the bed by her (guess for what)...
>
> *A: that's not the best time to roll your balls to Sophie, Mike!*
>
> *B: why..?*
>
> *A: she just got widowed!!!*
>
> *B: oh, no... Anyway...*

Comment: It is a vulgar and crude expression that sounds like it is mainly used by over-sexed 13 year old boys. Either that or invented by the Urban Dictionary contributor. That site (Urban Dictionary) is 'crowdsourced' which means that anybody at all can add a definition. It is not a reliable source of English. Some of the definitions, even if genuine, can be very local in their usage.

Comment: I gather from a brief Google search that 'In Texas we roll our balls to see how cold it is outside' so I suspect it literally means to touch or manipulate the testicles with the fingers, and figuratively to behave in an overtly or blatantly sexually suggestive fashion. Like I said, vulgar and crude. At the very least, severely informal.

Comment: The definition was posted January 8, 2022. That was a year ago. There are no thumbs up from the UD community and no thumbs down either. The first entry was posted  in 2008 and has earned ....drumroll... 6 thumbs up. Very safe to say that these entries are "fake" and totally made up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm English and work with teenagers and have never heard this phrase! You'd probably get some weird looks if you said it out loud.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually random contributor who didn't leave their name, this is a fine short answer to a simple question.  Citations are not much use here.  Please don't use the canned messages from the review list.  If you want to help a new contributor, please take the time to write a comment.

Comment: @JamesK this was a bot

Comment: Are you sure?  I don't think the OP is a bot.  And, as far as I know, these comments are generated when a human user chooses to leave them from the review queue - that is, they are not automatically generated.  They are assigned to "community" (for reasons that I fail to understand) and cannot be flagged or deleted, so my only option is to complain.

Answer (score 1):

Learners should not use the Urban Dictionary as a way of learning slang.

The nature of slang is that it can be very local, and very fast changing. It is quite possible that this vulgar slang was used by one group of boys in one high school.

It is also possible that it was made up by one bored teenager. Note the deliberate provocation in the example; it seems intended as a "shock joke".

When you are learning slang, you want to learn the slang of those people you meet from day to day.  If you are going to college in Baltimore, you want to learn the slang used by college students in Baltimore, not the slang used by teenage girls in Wisconsin, nor that used by old men in Berkshire.  So you need to learn it from the native speakers of English you interact with.

If you are learning English formally, in a country where English isn't the main language, and you don't have regular interactions with native speakers as close friends, then you really don't need slang. Instead you need the polite or more formal style that native speakers adopt when talking to strangers.

The short answer to your question is "No, that phrase doesn't have that meaning." and while it might be understood in context, it is hard to imagine a situation in which this would be the best way to express yourself.

Comment: I can just imagine a group of 12 year old boys saying 'I'm gonna roll my balls at X, hurr hurr' where X is a girl, and then X walks up and they all blush and stammer 'Oh, hello, X. Er, isn't it a nice day?'